# Breaker box has no power after a 220 plug shorted out

Tags: electrical

I had a 220 short out and the whole apartment went dark. So I reset every breaker but still no power has came back on anywhere in the house.

What do I need to do to trouble shoot this?

Comment: If I read correctly, surely you need to find a tripped breaker elsewhere in the house, not in the apartment.

Comment: No power in all of the apartment means the main breaker tripped, or wires burned out.  Might need to contact the landlord.  Shorting out 220/240 is a big short and might have caused more damage than just tripped breakers, that you need electrician to fix.

Comment: Have you checked for a main breaker next to your electric meter?

Comment: I would agree - if you're renting and resetting the tripped breaker doesn't restore power, the next thing is to call the landlord/apartment manager.

Comment: When resetting breakers, be sure to turn them all the way off before you turn them on.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably: if you have properly reset the breakers accessible to you inside your apartment, the breaker **elsewhere in the building** that **feeds** your apartment has tripped, and you need to contact your landlord. *That may involve explaining what you were doing that shorted out a 240V (if USA/Canada, 220 is decades out of date) outlet or circuit.*